# Why do we need to enable an API, for adding a registry in IoT core

Tags: google-cloud-platform, iot, google-cloud-iot

I am working on google cloud IoT core. I created a new project and associated a billing account to it. But when I wanted to add a registry to my project. In order to do that, it said, you need to enable the API first. I know what an API is in general sense. Is API in this context different? and why do i need to enable the API?

any help in this aspect is highly appreciated... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enabling the API is a prerequisite for using any product in GCP whether it's Iot Core, Compute Engine, other machine learning products, etc... Creating a registry invokes an API call, listing registries does the same, etc. For your reference [1](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/reference/rest/) [2](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/getting-started). With the API not enabled then you will not be able to use IoT Core or the other products.